# Is there a way to dynamically define the query fields?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Inspired by this great answer ([How to simplify `case` iteraction when the code is almost the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987417/how-to-simplify-case-iteraction-when-the-code-is-almost-the-same)) I though that there might be a way of doing something similar to this query to dynamically manipulate these fields:
`u.date, u.title, u.text` - `u.date_pt, u.title_pt, u.text_pt` - `u.date_es, u.title_es, u.text_es` -... 
in this query:

```
    def search(query, search_term, locale) do
        language =
          case locale do
            "pt" ->
              "Portuguese"
            "es" ->
              "Spanish"
            "fr" ->
              "Spanish"
            "de" ->
              "German"
            _ ->
              "English"
          end
        f = if locale in ~w(en pt es fr de), do: :"u.date_#{locale}, u.title_#{locale}, u.text_#{locale}", else: :u.date, u.title, u.text # This is WRONG, just to illustrate what's intended
        (from u in query,
        where: fragment("(to_tsvector(?, unaccent(?)) || to_tsvector(?, unaccent(?)) || to_tsvector(coalesce(?, unaccent(?)))) @@ plainto_tsquery(?, unaccent(?))", 
                         ^language, u.date, ^language, u.title, ^language, u.text, ^language, ^search_term),
        order_by: fragment("ts_rank((to_tsvector(?, ?) || to_tsvector(?, ?) || to_tsvector(coalesce(?, ?))), plainto_tsquery(?, ?)) DESC", 
                        ^language, u.date, ^language, u.title, ^language, u.text, ^language, ^search_term))
        |> Repo.all()
      end
```

Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `field/2` in the Ecto query for this. I'd do it like this:

```
suffix = if locale in ~w(pt es fr de), do: "_#{locale}", else: ""
```

Then, in the query, instead of

```
u.date
```

do:

```
field(u, ^:"date#{suffix}")
```

Similarly, `u.title` becomes `field(u, ^:"title#{suffix}")`, and so on.

Comment: Great again! Nevertheless I'm getting an error due to the `ts_tsvector('#{language}',`not working. It seems that I can't make that string interpolation there...

Comment: Was it working earlier? Is there any reason you're not using `?` and passing the language as an argument to `fragment`?

Comment: You're right, but even with `?` I have an issue: it is working when I have the language inserted directly, i.e. `(to_ts_vector('portuguese', unaccented(?)))...` but when I use `?`and then, `^language, u.name, ^language, field(u, ^:"name_label#{suffix}")?...I get an error: `(RuntimeError) type `regconfig` can not be handled by the types module Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.TypeModule`

Comment: I've just edited my question on that specific part so that it reflects the present error.

Comment: here you go: `to_tsvector(?::text::regconfig, ?)` make sure a `language` is a string before sending it to PG for a coersion.